# How do I use cdkDropList with free drag cdkDrag elements?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-cdk

Essentially what I want is this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ggglrnpvvrr?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-group-example.ts), but where the second list isn't a cdkDropList (or at the very least, can be dragged around as if they aren't in a cdkDropList).

The problem I'm having is if I use cdkDropList for the free drag cdkDrag elements, than at the end of the drag they pop right back to where they started (unless dropped in the normal list, and it leaves a placeholder behind while being dragged). If I don't use cdkDropList, than it seems the only thing I can react to is cdkDrag->(cdkDragReleased), in which case I have no way of telling if the draggable is being dropped into the list (at least as far as I can find).

In a nutshell, I'm trying to have sticky notes that can be dragged into, or pulled out of, an organized list.

Comment: Could you answer the question if you found the solution? I am looking for the same requirements.

Comment: @Tezra did you solve it? At least can you give some directions? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @DipeshRaichana did you solve it? Same issue here xD

Comment: @RafaeldeCastro Unfortunately Not yet :(

Comment: I made a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524084/how-to-change-an-angular-material-cdkdroplist-behavior-to-emulate-a-free-dropz. Some guy at the AngularCDK git start questioning me about it. Let's hope to get some clarity on this :D

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this issue was a [bug](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/22422). It has been resolved. If you see this issue, try upgrading.