# How to change an Angular Material CdkDroplist behavior to emulate a “free” dropzone?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

The goal is to make a full-width dropzone. In which I can drop "widgets" and drag them freely around the dropzone. But the twist is that I can also drop list widgets, in which I can drop other widgets as well..

So I have this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-free-dropzone-list?file=src/app/app.component.html)
With the code, and [this video](https://youtu.be/54uPoZwbfmI) showing the strange behavior

Any help?
I could remove the cdkdroplist directive and assume everything as a Draggable item but will lost the list features on the elements...

Same problem as this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566122/how-do-i-use-cdkdroplist-with-free-drag-cdkdrag-elements)

**app.component.html**

```
<div
  cdkDropList
  id="todo"
  [cdkDropListData]="todo"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="widgetIds"
  class="example-list board"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

    <div class="example-box widget item{{item.id}}"
      id="item{{item.id}}" 
      *ngFor="let item of todo" 
      cdkDrag
      (cdkDragReleased)="cdkDragReleased($event, item)"
      [cdkDragData]="item"
      [ngStyle]="{
                'transform': 'translate3d('+ item.dragPosition.x +'px,'+ item.dragPosition.y +'px,'+ item.dragPosition.z +'px)'
            }">{{item.label}}</div>
</div>

<div class="example-container widget widget-a">
  <h2>In Progress</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    id="inprogress"
    [cdkDropListData]="inprogress"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="widgetIds"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box item{{item.id}}"
      id="item{{item.id}}" 
      *ngFor="let item of inprogress" 
      cdkDrag
      (cdkDragReleased)="cdkDragReleased($event, item)"
      [cdkDragData]="item">{{item.label}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-container widget widget-b">
  <h2>Done</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    id="done"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="widgetIds"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box item{{item.id}}"
      id="item{{item.id}}" 
      *ngFor="let item of done" 
      cdkDrag
      (cdkDragReleased)="cdkDragReleased($event, item)"
      [cdkDragData]="item">{{item.label}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  widgetIds = ['todo', 'inprogress', 'done'];

  todo = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Item 1', dragPosition: { x: 45, y: 549, z: 0 } },
    { id: 2, label: 'Item 2', dragPosition: { x: 190, y: 236, z: 0 } },
    { id: 5, label: 'Item 5', dragPosition: { x: 93, y: 142, z: 0 } }
  ];

  inprogress = [
    { id: 3, label: 'Item 3', dragPosition: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 } },
    { id: 6, label: 'Item 6', dragPosition: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 } },
    { id: 7, label: 'Item 7', dragPosition: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 } }
  ];

  done = [
    { id: 4, label: 'Item 4', dragPosition: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 } },
    { id: 8, label: 'Item 8', dragPosition: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 } }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }

  cdkDragReleased(event: CdkDragRelease<any>, item) {
    const widDomElement: any = document.querySelector(`.item${item.id}`);
    const el: any = document.querySelector(`.cdk-drag-preview.item${item.id}`);
    let arrT = el.style.transform
      .replaceAll('px', '')
      .replaceAll(' ', '')
      .replaceAll(')', '')
      .replaceAll('translate3d(', '')
      .split(',');

    item.dragPosition = {
      x: Number(arrT[0]),
      y: Number(arrT[1]),
      z: Number(arrT[2])
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Will you add back the items to list again after dragging them out of cdkDropList?

Comment: Well, I might... If you saying start dragging, don't lose the mouse, then reposition the item back where it was, then yes. If you're saying drag the item, place it on the dropzone, then take it back to its original place on the list, then yes again... xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem within the Material CDK. The team solved this issue:

https://github.com/angular/components/commit/7508f46e7d1fd2eb0c20fdf8b913aacfcad5ea5a

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22407